# Modification on a sine wave before ADC

Tags: arduino, voltage, operational-amplifier

I actually have an  Arduino Due board, with everything working on it, using the ADC and the DAC. 
For my input for the ADC I need to have a signal 0-2.2V but my signal is actually between -5V to +5V. 
My idea is first to reduce it to be between -0.5V and +0.5 V, than add on offset of +0.5V to have it 0 - 1 V and then add a gain.

The first step is to reduce it but i don't know how to reduce a signal....

If someone has any idea everything can help me

Comment: If the impedance of the source is low, you can use a voltage divider.  If not, you're probably better off using a differential amplifier (Google "opamp" with "differental amplifier").

Comment: Thank you very much for that, i will try with the voltage divider, but do you know how to add an offset of 0.5V ?

Comment: You also should share some more information about the source of your signal. It will help people to better answer the question.

Comment: Yes maybe my signal is coming from a muscle stimulator and is between -5v to 5v, so with the voltage divider i have something between -0.5v to 0.5v, but then I need to add a DCoffset of 0.5V andI have no idea how to do that...

Comment: What supply rails are available on the Arduino?

Comment: **What is the source impedance of your voltage**?  It matters.  A lot.

Comment: the source of my voltage is going to be electrodes directly in the muscles

Comment: Maybe try drawing as much of the circuit as you can in the question.

Comment: Is there something between the muscles and the +/-5V? ..  because that sounds like a signal conditioner/amplifier output, not the raw signal (I would expect less than 50mV for the latter).

Comment: If you see a word like "impedance" in a technical discussion, and you don't know what it means, do not turn it into "" in your head.  Say something like "The phrase 'source impedance' means nothing to me -- what do you need to know to help me?"

Comment: There is no way you acquiring +/-5V signals from muscles, so you must have an Electromyography amplifier in play. You need to describe your acquisition equipment in more detail. It may already have an offset mechanism built in.

Answer (score 0):

Anything with gain and offset will work to match load requirements and CMRR.

Av = 2.2/10
Offset = 2.2/2 = 1.1

Details can be worked out easily with more info.

I might suggest HPF with series C and Rs = 78k then shunt Rp = 22k to 1.1V reference derived from Vdd or Vref on board.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this assume low source impedance. Since the comments indicate a very high source impedance you will need some signal conditioning up front. If you add a  buffer (such as a gain of 1 op-amp)  this circuit will work, however your buffer will require a +/-5V or more supply. If you already have a signal conditioning circuit that produces the +/-5V then this circuit should be fine.

Imagine this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTwfeX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We know Vout = (Vin/R1 + 5V/R3)*R1||R2||R3

If we pick R1||R2||R3 = 10K (assuming the chip in the Due is okay with 10K source impedance), we know from the gain \$\frac{\Delta Vout}{\Delta Vin}\$ = 2.2/10
so R1 = 45.4K.

Then we want Vout = 1.1V with Vin = 0 so R3 = 10K * 5/1.1 = 45.4K.

Finally, we want R1||R2||R3 = 10K so R2 = 17.86K

---

Now, if we want to scale this so the parts are closer to standard values we can go a bit lower, so lets pick R1 = R3 = 30.0K 1% so then R2 = 11.8K 1%.

Comment: Biometric signals have very high source impedances.  You cannot simply scale up the resistor values and make it work.  A signal amplifier will be required to buffer the source.

Comment: @scorpdaddy Surely. However +/-5V is not a plausible voltage for a biometric signal so I assume an amplifier, if not there will have to be a buffer and probably a relatively high gain amplifier.

Comment: agreed.  Good edits.  Upvoted.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers.Actually as this is a project I can have a +5 / -5 V voltage, and I think using an amplifier with a gain of one will be working fine tank you very much !

Answer (score -1):

If you have a low impedance source of a signal that varies from -5V to 5V and you want to create an output that varies from 0V-2.2V the easiest way is to use 3 resistors to make an output a weighted average of your input, 2.2V and 0V.

Connect the high side to your AVCC and the low side to your AVSS lines, and use higher value resistors by a factor of 10 maybe than shown in the schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzLgGg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I picked 100Ohms for R1 arbitrarily. You might want to scale it to better fit your system.

When the input is low the output is to be 0 so no current should flow through R3 and you can find the value of R2 by making the currents equal with the output being the desired 0V. Input/R1=2.2V/R2.

Then you can solve for R3 by equalizing currents through R1 and R2 when input and output are high.

Comment: The comments clearly indicate a very high source impedance.  An instrumentation amplifier or similar will be required.